# Align Text Center With Flexbox Column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to position text under an image with the flex-direction: column; property dead stock in the middle but I have no idea how to achieve this. It spans the same height but instead of an image it is text. I've added a background colour to the text to help you better understand what I'm trying to go for.

```css
.test {
display: flex;
}

.img1 {
background-image: url(http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/hd-model-wallpapers/hd-model-wallpapers-16.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 margin: 40px;
 height: calc(100vh - 80px);
 background-position: center center;
 flex: 1;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-left: 40px;
}

.test2 {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
}


.img2 {
background-image: url(http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/model-girl-hd-wallpaper/model-girl-hd-wallpaper-20.jpg);
flex: 1;
background-size: cover;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-right: 40px;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-top: 40px;
height: calc(50vh - 120px);
background-position: center center;
width: 50vw;
}

.test2 p {
flex: 1;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 40px;
font-size: 140px;
height: calc(50vh - 120px);
background-color: aqua;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<div class="img1"></div>
  <div class="test2">
    <div class="img2"></div>
    <p>ProntoToronto</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rxa7m0gs/

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're trying to do. You want the image on the right to be horizontally aligned? Or you want the text to be vertically aligned in the blue box? Or something else?

Comment: @Michael Coker vertically and horizontally centered in the blue box. I put a colour there to be able to see it being centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center the text in the paragraph, use `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;`

```css
.test {
    display: flex;
}

 .img1 {
    background-image: url(http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/hd-model-wallpapers/hd-model-wallpapers-16.jpg);
     background-size: cover;
     margin: 40px;
     height: calc(100vh - 80px);
     background-position: center center;
     flex: 1;
     margin-right: 0px;
     margin-left: 40px;
}

.test2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}


.img2 {
    background-image: url(http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/model-girl-hd-wallpaper/model-girl-hd-wallpaper-20.jpg);
    flex: 1;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    height: calc(50vh - 120px);
    background-position: center center;
    width: 50vw;
}

.test2 p {
    flex: 1;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    font-size: 140px;
    height: calc(50vh - 120px);
    background-color: aqua;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div class="img1"></div>
    <div class="test2">
    <div class="img2"></div>
    <p>ProntoToronto</p>
    </div>
</div>
```